# Copying files interactively: "cp: overwrite"

Tags: shell, cp, interactive

I'm trying to figure out what words does the `-i`nteractive option of `cp` accepts as input.

For your convenience, here's code that sets up files for experimentation.

```
touch example_file{1..3}
mkdir example_dir
cp example_file? example_dir
cp -i example_file? example_dir
```

The shell then asks interactively for each file whether it should be overwritten. It seems to accept all sorts of random input.

```
cp: overwrite 'example_dir/example_file1'? q
cp: overwrite 'example_dir/example_file2'? w
cp: overwrite 'example_dir/example_file3'? e
```

I tried looking into the [source code of `cp`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/cp.c), but I don't know C and searching for `overwrite` is of no help.

As far as I can tell it accepts some words as confirmation for overwriting, and everything else is taken as a no. The problem is even words like `ys` seem to be accepted as `yes`, so I don't know what works and what doesn't.

I'd like to know how exactly does this work and to have some proof of it by means of documentation or **intelligible** snippets of source code.

Comment: In the interest of making this not too localized, I can accept unintelligible source code as well, but it will be hard for me to accept an answer if I can't be convinced of what the code is doing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/cp.html) only specifies that the response need to be "affirmative" for the copying to be carried out when `-i` is in effect.

For GNU `cp`,
the actual input at that point is handled by a function called `yesno()`.  This function is defined in the [`lib/yesno.c`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=gnulib.git;a=blob;f=lib/yesno.c;h=0a5872723bc461dfd70fca99010c0de804e5dafe;hb=HEAD) file in the gnulib source distribution, and looks like this:

```c
bool
yesno (void)
{
  bool yes;

#if ENABLE_NLS
  char *response = NULL;
  size_t response_size = 0;
  ssize_t response_len = getline (&response, &response_size, stdin);

  if (response_len <= 0)
    yes = false;
  else
    {
      /* Remove EOL if present as that's not part of the matched response,
         and not matched by $ for example.  */
      if (response[response_len - 1] == '\n')
        response[response_len - 1] = '\0';
      yes = (0 < rpmatch (response));
    }

  free (response);
#else
  /* Test against "^[yY]", hardcoded to avoid requiring getline,
     regex, and rpmatch.  */
  int c = getchar ();
  yes = (c == 'y' || c == 'Y');
  while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
    c = getchar ();
#endif

  return yes;
}
```

If NLS ("National Language Support") is *not* used, you can see that the only reply that the function returns *true* for is a response that starts with an upper or lower case `Y` character. Any additional or other input is discarded.

If NLS *is* used, the `rpmatch()` function is called to determine whether the response was affirmative or not.  The purpose of the `rpmatch()` NLS library function is to determine whether a given string is affirmative or not (with support for internationalisation).

On BSD systems, the corresponding function is found in [`src/bin/cp/utils.c`](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/src/bin/cp/utils.c?rev=1.47&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup):

```c
/*
 * If the file exists and we're interactive, verify with the user.
 */
int
copy_overwrite(void)
{
        int ch, checkch;

        if (iflag) {
                (void)fprintf(stderr, "overwrite %s? ", to.p_path);
                checkch = ch = getchar();
                while (ch != '\n' && ch != EOF)
                        ch = getchar();
                if (checkch != 'y' && checkch != 'Y')
                        return (0);
        }
        return 1;
}
```

This is essentially the same as the non-NLS code path in the GNU code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was unable to find the source other than on [opencoverage.net](http://www.opencoverage.net/coreutils/index_html/source_160.html). Any chance you can link to it on http://git.savannah.gnu.org ? As I understand it (and correct me if I'm wrong), this is the closest to the truth that we can have (other than looking into what's inside one's machine), so a link there would be very much appreciated.

Comment: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=gnulib.git;a=tree;f=lib;h=5479abd47c21d957709b10ca575da7be37b8ec97;hb=HEAD

Comment: @JeffSchaller Thank you very much. I suggested an [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/284977) to the answer in order to include [this](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=gnulib.git;a=tree;f=lib).

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the source code and search for `interactive` you can see that it sets `x.interactive = I_ASK_USER;`, so you can search in this and other files where `I_ASK_USER` is checked.

In `copy.c` you will find this symbol near a function call `overwrite_ok`, and this function contains a call to a function `yesno`.

The rest is left as an exercise for the reader. ;-)

Comment: I honestly appreciate the exercise, and even chuckled. Alas, I was unable to find the source code and for this reason I'm preferring Kusalananda's answer a little more. Thank you very much.